# Node.js promise not returning object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I am writing an authentication module that needs to write a query to return an array of users (in my `authentication.js`. However, when I call the function in my `home.js`, the function returns a promise object like:

```
Promise {
  _bitField: 0,
  _fulfillmentHandler0: undefined,
  _rejectionHandler0: undefined,
  _promise0: undefined,
  _receiver0: undefined }
```

In my code snippet, I commented where I get a promise object and a users array.

My `home.js`:

```
module.exports = function (req, res) {


var rawCookie = req.headers.cookie;


var result1 = Promise.resolve(authentication.authenticate(rawCookie))
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log(result); //returns the correct users array
        return result; 
    });

console.log(result1); //returns a promise object (should return the users array

};
```

My `authentication.js`:

```
exports.authenticate = Promise.method(function(rawCookie) { 
    var cookie = parseCookie.parseCookie(rawCookie);
    return knex('users')
        .where('session_key', cookie)
        .then(function(data){ 
            return data //returns array of users
    }); 
});
```

Comment: No, you've got a promise *for* the user array. That's fine. There's no way to get the array synchronously.

Comment: You realize it's asynchronous ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/1348195